# How can I add OpenLayers layer from the Python console?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am new to the Python console. How can I add a layer from the OpenLayers plugin from the Python console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renaud, there are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Query QGIS's interface to find and trigger the appropriate menu
   action.
2. Work directly with the already-loaded OpenLayers plugin.

Solution #1 is pretty straightforward. OpenLayers plugin offers a good solution to #2, which will help you understand working with other plugins as well. Here is how both are accomplished.

**Trigger OpenLayers plugin menu action**

```
layeract = 'Google Physical'
plugmenu = qgis.utils.iface.pluginMenu()
olmenu = False
for act in plugmenu.actions():
    if 'OpenLayers' in act.text():
        olmenu = act
        break
if olmenu:
    for act in olmenu.menu().actions():
        if layeract in act.text():
            act.trigger()
```

**Work directly with OpenLayers plugin**

```
try:
    olplugin = qgis.utils.plugins['openlayers']
    ol_gphyslayertype = olplugin.olLayerTypeRegistry.getById(0)
    olplugin.addLayer(ol_gphyslayertype)
except KeyError:
    print 'OpenLayers plugin not loaded.'
```

This latter solution probably needs a little more explaining.

```
-> olplugin = qgis.utils.plugins['openlayers']
```

Get the OpenLayers plugin instance from qgis.utils's plugin registry.

```
-> ol_gphyslayertype = olplugin.olLayerTypeRegistry.getById(0)
```

Get the 'Google Physical' layer type object from OpenLayers's layer type registry. Open *[path-to-user-plugins]/openlayers/openlayers_plugin.py* and starting at line #111 you will see the order the layer types are assigned to the registry. They are given IDs starting with 0 (see rest of module for how that's done).

```
-> olplugin.addLayer(ol_gphyslayertype)
```

Loads the layer into QGIS's map canvas.

There may be other solutions as well, but those are the basics that I could find.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the second option and it is working fine.python console seems very powerful !

Comment: Is there an updated solution now that OpenLayers appear under the `Web` submenu instead of `Plugins`?

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 2.4 Chugiak, the OpenLayers plugin has moved in the QGIS Gui to `Web->OpenLayers plugin`, hence the first method described above won't work anymore. I updated it to match the new menu structure, see [my answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120147/add-openlayers-layer-from-qgiss-python-console/120362#120362).

Still, it would be interesting to know how to adapt the second method to QGIS 2.4 and above.