# Add OpenLayers layer from QGIS's Python console?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

On QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak the Openlayers plugin is found under `Web` menu rather than the `Plugins` menu. How can you use the Python console to add a Openlayers Google Maps layer?

The following code give us the error `OpenLayers plugin not loaded.`

```
try:
    olplugin = qgis.utils.plugins['openlayers']
    ol_gphyslayertype = olplugin.olLayerTypeRegistry.getById(0)
    olplugin.addLayer(ol_gphyslayertype)
except KeyError:
    print 'OpenLayers plugin not loaded.'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the direct way as you tried in your example looks much cleaner, however, I did not find out either how to achieve this in QGIS 2.4.

So long, as a workaround, you can navigate through the menu interface manually to open the desired map from the OpenLayers plugin. In the following code, set the variables `mapProvider` and `openLayersMap` to your desired entries from the QGIS->Web->OpenLayers plugin menu. See inline comments for further explanation.

```
mapProvider = 'Google Maps' #also use e.g. 'OpenStreetMap', 'Bing Maps' etc. as given in the Web->OpenLayers plugin menu
openLayersMap = 'Google Physical' #also use e.g. 'Google Streets', 'OpenStreetMap', 'Bing Road' etc. as given in the Web->OpenLayers plugin menu

webMenu = qgis.utils.iface.webMenu() #get object of the Web menu of QGIS

for webMenuItem in webMenu.actions(): #open the Web menu of QGIS and loop through the list of web plugins
    if 'OpenLayers plugin' in webMenuItem.text(): #look for OpenLayers plugin entry in the Web menu
        openLayersMenu = webMenuItem #and open it

        for openLayersMenuItem in openLayersMenu.menu().actions(): #open the OpenLayers plugin menu entry and loop through the list of map providers
            if mapProvider in openLayersMenuItem.text(): #if the desired mapProvider is found
                mapProviderMenu = openLayersMenuItem #open its menu entry

                for map in mapProviderMenu.menu().actions(): #loop through the list of maps for the opened provider
                    if openLayersMap in map.text(): #if the desired map entry is found
                        map.trigger() #click the entry to load the map as a layer
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the method you are using work by simply changing the name from 'openlayers' to 'openlayers_plugin'.

```
olplugin = qgis.utils.plugins['openlayers_plugin']
```